# Changes in python mode Emacs 24 → 26

Tags: python

Certain key combos seem to have changed behaviour from emacs 24 to emacs 26 in python mode (`python.el`). Notably:

## Emacs 24:

(no python shell open yet)

<kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>: Run python: ... ; Dedicated process?; Eval buffer

<kbd>C-c C-z</kbd>: Run python: ... ; Dedicated process?; switch to shell

## Emacs 26:

(no python shell open)

<kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>: Open a shell first with <kbd>C-c C-p</kbd>...

<kbd>C-c C-z</kbd>: Open a shell first with <kbd>C-c C-p</kbd>...

If a shell is open in 26, all python files are directed to this shell. Haven't found out how to open a dedicated shell for separate files.

Is there any way to get the Emacs 24 behaviour back, at least partially?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a per-buffer python process using `C-u C-c C-p` (`run-python`), then, you should be able to use `C-c C-c` and `C-c C-z` on such process.